# Unable to obtain development certificate in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning-profile, iphone-developer-program

I'm trying to get a development certificate for first time going to *Organizer > Devices > Library > Provisioning Profiles*. There, I click the refresh button at the bottom, and I'm promted to enter my Apple Developer username and the password. I do, but it doesn`t connect, I'm shown a popup with a "The request timed out" message. If I enter my Apple Developer credentials in the Member Center website, I can access correctly. Why could this be happening? Could it be because I don't have an "Admin" profile for the Developer Programs (I'm a "Member" user)?

Thanks!

Comment: Just try again after few minutes

Comment: I had no idea how to get to the option in Xcode to create a Developer certificate, and this question was the only place on the internet I could find after a while of searching that actually answered that question.  (For anyone interested, I have **helped edit a detailed list of steps to properly codesign a Qt application on OS X** here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918932/368896)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your firewall/network settings too.

Comment: Xcode seems to check for components/documentation updates... anyway, where can I check the proxy settings for Xcode?

Comment: xcode sometimes uses port which may be closed by your network admins.

Comment: It certainly was a network issue, nothing to do with my developer user profile. Thanks